# user selects substring in python

Tags: python, string, substring

How do I write a program that say, for a string 'IIXIIXIIXIIX' would allow a user  to input which substring 'x' they want to replace with another string?

So if user enters 1, it would be the first x etc. Essentially how do I relate user input to string position? So far I have

```
string = 'IIXIIXIIXIIX'
substring = 'X'
ss = input("Which substring would you like to replace: ")
if ss == '1':
    string = string.replace('X', 'Y')
    print(string)
```

this simply replaces ALL the 'X' with 'Y', but I'm looking to replace individual 'X' based on user input. How could I do this?

Comment: i have "tried" to do it with string.find and string.index but i don't know how to make user input relate to index position of substring

Comment: Is the actual format of your string going to look like `IIXIIXIIXIIX` or is that just an example for random letters with x's inbetween?

Comment: One idea could be to split the string on the `X`, then stitch together with `join`s, replacing just one of them according to your index.

Comment: that was just a random example. i will be using this for a program based on the MU game https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MU_puzzle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely not the most elegant, but this seems to work:

```
string1 = 'IIXIIXIIXIIX'
substring = 'X'
replacement='B'
ss = input("Which substring would you like to replace: ")
list1= string1.split(substring)
print  substring.join(list1[:ss])+replacement+substring.join(list1[ss:])
```

Output:

```
Which substring would you like to replace: 3
IIXIIXIIBIIX
```

You'd still need to properly treat edge cases like position `0` and going past the number of occurrences of the substring.

Comment: Looks good, thank you. Could you please explain to me what repl is? I've never seen that before and Google didn't help me.

Comment: that's just the variable containing what letter you want to replace x with, in his example the letter B

Comment: Good point, I meant the variable `replacement`, but `repl` has other meanings, shouldn't have used that. Will fix.